# How can I have two select statements in my view using multidimensional arrays from my routes.php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Simply put, I want to have a survey in a view that asks how many beers a person drinks in a week and how many cigarettes they smoke.  In my routes.php, I've tried:

```
for ($numcigs=1; $numcigs<=60; $numcigs++) {
    $data['numcigs'][$numcigs] = $numcigs . ' cigarettes';
}
```

Then, in my view I have:

```
{{ Form::select('numcigs',$data['numcigs']) }}
```

Unfortunately, that gives me the error: Undefined variable: data

The part that gets me so confused is how I could create two selects from one array defined in my route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$numcigs` directly:

```
{{ Form::select('numcigs', $numcigs) }}
```

All the array keys in `$data` are automatically [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)ed to the view, so that you can access them directly.

---

The above assumes you're passing your `$data` into the view:

```
View::make('path/to/view', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  Unfortunately I get an error: Undefined variable: numcigs

Comment: No need!  By you asking me to show it, I realized my error.  I had been trying a number of things before coming here to ask and I was passing $data['numcigs'] in my View::make.  I should have simply been passing $data.  Now it works!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Chris Farrugia you should mark this as the correct answer if that's the case.

Comment: Jason, I wanted to last night but it said I had to wait.  It's marked now.